# Does a power cord use energy when it is not pugged into a Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, power, energy

In order to save energy I consider pulling the power cord out of the wall after my Mac has been recharges.

Does a power cord use energy when it is not pugged into a Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the charger will use power when plugged in, but much less than when it is actually charging.

Once the mac is charged then unplug the power supply - it serves no purpose leaving it in, but if you forget it is not a huge waste of power.

The term for this is vampire power and if you assume the MacBook charger in this test was equivalent to 3 of the tested chargers combined, it might consume 18 cents of electricity per year in the US.

- https://www.howtogeek.com/231886/tested-should-you-unplug-chargers-when-youre-not-using-them/